# Scrollbar in easygui?

Tags: python, scrollbar, easygui

Is there any way of getting a scroll bar using the easygui module or a modified version of it? I found a file online called thinking_py.txt, and, after converting it to python format, found that it did indeed have a version of easygui with a scroll-bar. However, according to the launcher, at least, the module is rife with syntax errors. I don't want to mess around with it too much, so what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you refer to the application `thinking.py` from Steve Ferg which is part of his work [Thinking in Tkinter](http://thinkingtkinter.sourceforge.net/).

I just downloaded it and works like a charm.

Not sure what the problem is, but I would not keep putting the blame on Ferg's syntax errors. Consequently, my advice to your question is you to take some time and **learn** tkinter. You can do it using the very same Thinking in Tkinter you already have.

Forget EasyGui, it is a wrapper of tkinter that, for the shake of simplicity, is stealing from you basic things like the **capacity of selecting the size of your frame**, the very first thing one want to do with a frame that occupies most of the screen.

In Ferg's site there are also other interesting links for learning tkinter.

Finally, this is what you need for a [scrollbar in a text control](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm):

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

text = Text(root, wrap=WORD, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
text.pack()

data = 'I will study some tkinter\n'
for i in range(100):
    text.insert(END, data)

scrollbar.config(command=text.yview)

mainloop()
```

[image]